# Using Ajax in django template to update an element

Tags: json, ajax, django, templates

So I have a button that is suppose to "Add" an "Item" to a list and update the list on the same page without refreshing it.

Adding the Item without redirecting worked. but the element is not refreshed properly

Here is my script:

```
<div id="list">
    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item.name }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<button id="add" type="submit">+</button>

<script>
    $('#add').click(function () {
        $.get('/url/page/', function (data) {
            $('#list').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

views.py

```
def add_to_list(request, item_id, list_id): 
      item, created = List.objects.get_or_create(list_id=list_id, 
      item_id=item_id)
     return HttpResponse(request)
```

I feel like I have to add something in the views? and maybe use json code?

Comment: Can we see your template as well?

Comment: Sure, I added the full code just now.

Answer (score 0):

You should append the result of your request to the `div` element. Try this:

```
 $('#add').click(function () {
    $.get('/url/page/', function (data) {
        $('#list').append(data);
    });
});
```

Assuming that `data` that you receive from `GET` request is not an object but just a string. If it is an object add `data.name`:

```
$('#list').append(data.name)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I made a mistake in the question. but this is the way i actaully done it. but didn't work

Comment: @DjangoGuy can you `console.log(data)` and let me know the result?

Comment: @DjangoGuy Are you sure that you are doing `append(data)`, not `html(data)`? You should write this command before `append(data)`

Comment: I was using html(data) now I changed it to append(data) I also tried append(data.name) and still didn't work.

Comment: @DjangoGuy please tell me the output of `console.log(data)` which you should write above `$('#list').append(data);`

Comment: If i did it correctly, I think the result is : (index):292

Comment: @DjangoGuy I don't think you did it correctly. Please take a look this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksp3m5yk/1/) and do the same.

Comment: does this look like the result you're looking for: VM1408:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:17